# Post data from client to Node server

Tags: node.js, post

I can post data to node server though i can't access the data in my app.get route.

orders.hbs (ajax):

```
$.post( "/show_items", { o_id: result } );
```

app.js:

```
app.post ('/show_items', function(req,res){
  var order_num = req.body.o_id;
});

app.get('/orders',authenticationMiddleware(), function(request, response){

  console.log(order_num);
...

}
```

The problem is that in my app.get i can't access the $order_num variable. How can i access the variable and use it?

Answer (score 0):

As `order_num` gets defined in `app.post` it is a local variable and only available under that scope. If you want to access it in `app.get` you need to define it before and then just set it:

```
var order_num;

app.post ('/show_items', function(req,res){
    order_num = req.body.o_id;
});

...

app.get('/orders',authenticationMiddleware(), function(request, response){
    console.log(order_num);
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks, though for some reason order_num doesn't save its change after app.post. So i am still stuck.

Comment: It most likely does. I guess what you are encountering is that `app.get` is called before `order_num` has a value. You should consider putting the `app.get` request somewhere where you are sure that it already has a value like in `app.post` direclty.

Comment: I assume you are correct. My problem is that I want that data to constantly change. When the user clicks the row on the table, ajax sends a post to app.js and the variable order_num changes. How can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

I want to know the use-case before answering. As you sent the data in POST-API, it should ideally be available/used by all middlewares (functions) defined to POST-API.

@Yoni: You are trying to use info passed in POST API (under property req.body.order_num) in altogether different GET API.

But if you want to access it anyway then solution shared by @Bostrot works fine.

Comment: Hi, 

I have an html page with a table. I would like that when the user clicks on a row, it sends the id of the row to app.get route in my app.js node server.

Comment: while invoking GET API, pass the **row_id** as   
`htttp://domain_name.com/v1/path/endpoint?row_id=12`  


In server code (In API), fetch and use **row_id** as   
`var row_id = req.query.row_id`